# Can't import modules (scripts) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to import my `Main.py` file to the `GUI.py` file which is in the same folder. I tried all these ways, but it doesn't work well. I'm using Python 3.10 and PyCharm as IDE.

```py
import Main  # it just runs the Main.py files, doesn't import variables
import Main.py  # same as above
from .Main import *  # error occurred: attempted relative import with no known parent package
from . import Main  # same as above
```

I tried creating a package, too (made a new folder and put `Main.py` and `_init_.py` in it), but this didn't work either.

Please help, I'm stuck here. Thanks!

Comment: Check if my answer clarifies your understanding when you say "_it just runs the Main.py_".

Answer (score 4):

`import Main` is likely what you want. Just note that the variables from the `Main` module will need to be accessed as attributes of the `Main` object. That is, if a variable or function is called `x` in `Main.py` then it will be called `Main.x` after it's imported in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding the `import`, because its function is to actually run the python file. Two things:

Firstly, for your `Main.py` to be an actual module, you need to have in it a condition that tells the interpreter to do not run his stuff when importing it like when you call it directly from a shell:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # put here everything you want to run when calling Main.py directly, but not when importing
```

Secondly, the variables you defined in `Main.py` are actually being imported, but you're probably trying to access them the wrong way. Look:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.SCHED_FIFO
4
>>> from os import *
>>> SCHED_FIFO
4
>>>
```

Be careful if you'll do an `import *` like above, because you will overwrite local objects if you have objects with the same name:

```
>>> SCHED_FIFO = 0
>>> SCHED_FIFO
0
>>> from os import *
>>> SCHED_FIFO
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the . before Main. Like this:

```py
from Main import *
```

Comment: This would also work, but I don't think we should be encouraging wildcard imports! https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8zej2c/eli5_what_are_wildcard_imports_and_why_should_i/

Answer (score 0):

Say you have following file structure:

```
GUI.py
    |
    |__
       folder
         |
         |__
            MAIN.py
```

So if you want to acces main.py, add a blank `__init__.py` in the folder of `main.py`. Then access it using:

```
from folder import MAIN as m

OR

import folder.MAIN as m
```

And if want to access the variable,

Access global variable in main.py using `m.variable_name`
and local variable in side a function by `m.function_name_variable_name`, but note you have to write local variable in function like `function_name.variable_name`

```
def a():
    a.name="Faraaz"
a()
print(a.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are your variables lie? If it lies outside some function, it should be Constant. If it lies inside the function, it is a different story.

Guess I have 2 files like this (maybe same as you have)
[image]

My main.py has a Constant with the value "something"
[image]

My gui.py has imported the main.py
[image]

The Constant from main.py should works well in gui.py
[image]